# Linked list destructor not working

Tags: c++, linked-list, destructor, doubly-linked-list

I've written a destructor for a doubly linked list which is not working properly. There's a loop to delete the values. The line-of-control comes out of the that loop but the program doesn't finish. I mean, the main does not end.

Never mind, I figured it out.

Comment: Difficult to say anything without seeing the main() part.

Comment: On what line does it get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the destructor cimpler. For example

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList() 
{
    for ( ListItem *node = head; node; ) 
    {
        ListItem *temp = node;
        node = node->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    head = nullptr;
}
```

Or

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList() 
{
    while ( head ) 
    {
        ListItem *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }

    head = nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: move `delete node;` line. 
If only head exist it makes error.

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    ListItem* node = head;
    ListItem* temp = NULL;

    if (head != NULL && head->next == NULL) {
        delete head;
    } else {
        while (node->next) {
            temp = node;
            node = node->next;
            delete temp;
        }
        delete node;
    }
}
```

Or remove if statment.

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    ListItem* node = head;
    ListItem* temp = NULL;

    while (node->next) {
         temp = node;
         node = node->next;
         delete temp;
    }
     delete node;
}
```

Comment: this may happen.  if (head != NULL && head->next == NULL)  delete head; delete node;